# Problem in getting this output using Join in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I want to show a output like this,

```
+------------+--------------+---------------------+---------------+-----------+--------------+-----------+
| segment_id | segment_name | segment_description | tot_questions | tot_marks | marks_obtain | neg_marks |
+------------+--------------+---------------------+---------------+-----------+--------------+-----------+
| 10006      | MCQ SECTION  |                     | 5             | 20        |              | -.5       |
| 10007      | Non-MCQ      |                     | 5             | 20        |              | 0         |
+------------+--------------+---------------------+---------------+-----------+--------------+-----------+
```

Now here are my tables that will be used for join,

**MockTestMaster** (used column tot_marks)

```
+---------+------------+-------------+-------------+
| test_id | test_name  | total_Marks | template_id |
+---------+------------+-------------+-------------+
| 1       | MOCKTEST-X | 20          | 1           |
+---------+------------+-------------+-------------+
```

**MockTestDetails** (segment_id, segment_name, tot_questions)

```
+---------+------------+--------------+------------------------+
| test_id | section_id | section_name | total_section_question |
+---------+------------+--------------+------------------------+
| 1       | 10006      | MCQ SECTION  | 5                      |
| 1       | 10006      | MCQ SECTION  | 5                      |
| 1       | 10006      | MCQ SECTION  | 5                      |
| 1       | 10006      | MCQ SECTION  | 5                      |
| 1       | 10006      | MCQ SECTION  | 5                      |
| 1       | 10007      | Non-MCQ      | 5                      |
| 1       | 10007      | Non-MCQ      | 5                      |
| 1       | 10007      | Non-MCQ      | 5                      |
| 1       | 10007      | Non-MCQ      | 5                      |
| 1       | 10007      | Non-MCQ      | 5                      |
+---------+------------+--------------+------------------------+
```

**prd_template_question_type** (used columns neg_marks)

```
+-------------+-------------+----------------+----------------+
| template_id | is_mcq_type | is_nonmcq_type | marks_if_wrong |
+-------------+-------------+----------------+----------------+
| 1           | 1           | 0              | -0.5           |
| 1           | 0           | 1              | 0              |
+-------------+-------------+----------------+----------------+
```

**prd_templatesection** (I could use this table,but on my application user could add a section and which will not be inserted in this table because it will change the original template,so I inserted that section in MockTestDetails table)

```
+-------------+------------+--------------+------------------------+-------------------+
| template_id | section_id | section_name | total_section_question | sectiontype_isMcq |
+-------------+------------+--------------+------------------------+-------------------+
| 1           | 10006      | MCQ SECTION  | 5                      | true              |
| 1           | 10007      | Non-MCQ      | 5                      | false             |
+-------------+------------+--------------+------------------------+-------------------+
```

Now problem of getting my output is the `marks_if_wrong` column of `prd_template_question_type` table.

Now here is the deal how to get neg_marks: if `sectiontype_isMcq` of `prd_templatesection` is `true`, then grab `marks_if_wrong` column of `prd_template_question_type`.

I tried this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    md.section_id AS segment_id,
    md.section_name AS segment_name,
    '' AS segment_description,
    md.total_section_question as tot_questions,
    total_Marks AS tot_marks,
    '' AS marks_obtain,
    '' AS neg_marks
    --prd_template_question_type.marks_if_wrong AS neg_marks
FROM
    dbo.MocktestDetails md
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.MockTestMaster mm ON mm.test_id = md.test_id 
INNER JOIN 
    prd_templatesection pts ON pts.template_id = mm.template_id
WHERE 
    mm.test_id = 1;
```

Here is a [fiddle of this problem](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8578b/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code

```
WITH cte_sales AS (
     SELECT DISTINCT md.section_id  AS segment_id,
            md.section_name         AS segment_name,
            ''                      AS segment_description,
            md.total_section_question AS tot_questions,
            total_Marks             AS tot_marks,
            ''                      AS marks_obtain,
            pts.template_id         AS template_id
            --prd_template_question_type.marks_if_wrong AS neg_marks
     FROM   dbo.MocktestDetails md
            INNER JOIN dbo.MockTestMaster mm
                 ON  mm.test_id = md.test_id
            INNER JOIN prd_templatesection pts
                 ON  pts.template_id = mm.template_id
     WHERE  mm.test_id = 1
 )

 SELECT segment_id,
        segment_name,
        segment_description,
        tot_questions,
        tot_marks,
        marks_obtain,
        COALESCE(
            (
                SELECT TOP 1 marks_if_wrong
                FROM   prd_template_question_type AS ptqt
                       JOIN prd_templatesection AS pt
                            ON  ptqt.template_id = pt.template_id
                WHERE  ptqt.template_id = cte.template_id
                       AND pt.section_id = cte.segment_id
            ),
            '0'
        )
 FROM   cte_sales AS cte
```